# functions in modules are getting executed first and print statements are not getting executed even after placing them first(Before the function call)

Tags: python, function, module

I am new to python and trying out my own pet project. So, my project directories look like this:
[image]

Now in my ***main.py*** file I have imported ***models*** module
`from models.eq_melting import *  from models.frac_melting import *`. After that I put some print statements :
[image]

Now the problem is whatever function that is residing in files of module models, is getting executed first rather than the print statements.
[image]

Please help me to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Please upload the code and error message as text instead of image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a module you are in fact executing it, so every statement in the module will get run. If it is just function `def`s then you will just add those functions to the namespace, but not actually run the code they contain. However if it contains `print` or other statements then they will get executed.

To summarise when you import a module you execute everything in that module.

This is also why you see very often code that looks like
`if __name__ == "__main__"` at the bottom of many modules. If the module gets imported the `if` condition won't be satisfied, but if the module is executed directly as a script then the `if` condition will be satisfied and the code will run.

As a side note you should do your best to avoid `from module import *` - it will make debugging ten times harder as it makes it impossible for the computer (and the human) to know where items in its name space came from.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I added if __name__ == "__main__" : main() at the bottom of each function like you said. Sadly, I can not upvote your answer as I don't have 15 reputation. But again, thanks a lot.